# Matpliblib colormap with peak at center and zero at edges

Tags: matplotlib, colormap

I am looking for a custom colormap that highlights the center (value of 1) and just has white color at the edges (values of 0 and 2). Ideally there should be a gradient from 1 to [0, 2].

Usual colormaps do the opposite: diverges from center (white at center).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Pls check the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`from_list`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) method from [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html) for this from the `matplotlib.colors` module.

Here, we give 3 colors as a list (`["white", "red", "white"]`). This can easily be customised by changing any of those color names.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('wrw', ["white", "red", "white"], N=256)

a = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01).reshape(20, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

p = ax.pcolormesh(a, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=2)

fig.colorbar(p)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create based on availbale colormaps from matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

def show_cmap(ax, cmap):
    n = 256
    ax.imshow(np.tile(np.arange(n), [int(n*0.20),1]),
              cmap=cmap,
              interpolation="nearest", aspect="auto")
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    

c1 = plt.cm.Blues(range(0, 128))
c2 = c1[::-1]
c = np.vstack([c1, c2])
cmap = ListedColormap(c)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
show_cmap(ax, cmap)
```

[image]